# Events not propagating downward using dispatchEvent

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

In my angular tests, I have these two elements, where the graph is located within the wrapper:

```js
const wrapper = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#canvas-wrapper'));
const graph = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#inner-canvas'));
```

The app uses a `mousemove` binding inside the graph element, and for testing purposes I've also placed one on the wrapper.

```js
  wrapperMouseHandler(event) {
    console.log('wrapper offsets', event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
    console.log('wrapper clients', event.clientX, event.clientY);
  }

  didMoveOnGraph({ offsetX: x, offsetY: y }) {
    console.log('didMoveOnGraph', x, y);
    ... the rest of the method ...
  }
```

When I move my mouse around in the app, moving on the graph bubbles and prints all 3 log statements.

I want to test mouse activity throughout the entire component (which has some other mouse-aware areas) and so I want to test that movements in certain locations of the wrapper trigger the handlers in their children (e.g., the graph).

When I use `dispatchEvent` on the graph, I can get it to bubble up to the wrapper. But I need the opposite behavior, as described above -- "bubbling down" from the wrapper to the graph.

Can I do this without dispatching a mousemove on the child directly? How?

Comment: Events don't go downwards in the DOM. You would have to create custom events that don't bubble and attach them to shoot downwards explicitly.

Comment: I guess I don't need them to actually bubble downwards. The behavior of the frontmost element receiving the event is fine. I just need something in my test that places the mouse and clicks, but doesn't directly dispatch the event to the desired target, since the event reaching the correct target is what I'm trying to test.